# Does jQuery run when printing from browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

I have the following code to run on the rendered template page after selecting to print from  the browser:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("td:contains('Labour')").next("td").addClass("white");
    var thisTr = $("td:contains('Labour')").parent();
    thisTr.children().eq(2).addClass("white");
    thisTr.children().eq(3).addClass("white");
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```css
 @media print {
      body           { margin:auto; }
      .section       { page-break-inside:avoid; }
      div#sfWebDebug { display:none; }
      .white {color: white;}
    }
```

I checked the code and it's working when in a normal browser window: http://jsfiddle.net/elen/vArH8/

But the `white` class doesn't seem apply in the pop-up to print. I tried in Chrome and Firefox.

Do browsers allow JavaScript to run when printing?

---

answering my own stupid question - it would help if I added jquery plugin to the template first!

and the following code works perfectly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var thisTr = $("td:contains('Labour')").parent();
    thisTr.children().eq(1).empty();
    thisTr.children().eq(2).empty();
    thisTr.children().eq(3).empty();
    window.print();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you not just prove that they don't?

Comment: `if (window.matchMedia("print").matches) {
    ....
}`

Comment: @Waleed Khan - is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @WaleedKhan I doubt he just proved that, since it's not true... not sure what's going on in this case.

Comment: @codeiz and where this code should be? parent window or template using to print?

Comment: how about this http://trevordavis.net/blog/unobtrusive-javascript-print-link-with-jquery

Comment: @Elen , sorry at first i miss understood your question ! i though you meant how to know that the pageis print

Comment: @Jeremy Banks so you reckon it should work? what do you think I should check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an issue of javascript, it's just that printers don't print white. It will often discard CSS to make things more readable.

Do you want to just hide those fields? You can use the .empty() method to achieve that more easily.

Comment: simple and clever =) i'll try this

Comment: To support this: when I try the example in Chrome on OS X, the `.white` fields are displayed as light grey. The class *is* being added and having an effect, it's just not what you'd expect.

Comment: `$("td:contains('Labour')").next("td").empty();` - didn't work either =(

Comment: @Elen Can you describe what part isn't working? Are the fields still displaying when you print? When I look through print preview and when I exported to .xps these fields are empty as intended.

Comment: @k.odell yes, i still see the content of the <td>'s but when i look page source - the code is there, but not doing anything.. i dont export - just print page from browser

Comment: @Elen perhaps someone else can confirm then. I don't have access to a printer so the best I can do is print preview/export.